# Resolution for FreeBSD text console

Tags: terminal, freebsd, console, resolution

I am using FreeBSD 13 which I boot from grub.

My monitor is 1280x768 native resolution, but FreeBSD text console uses it at 640x480:

```
VT(vga): resolution 640x480
```

I tried the following in my `/boot/loader.conf` which did not help:

```
kern.vt.fb.default_mode="1280x768"
efi_max_resolution="1280x768"
```

How do I force a boot in 1280x768 resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VT system relies upon, internally, *display* drivers to actually supply a display system to it.  The `vga` in `VT(vga)` says that it's using a VGA display driver.  It could say, for example `VT(efifb)` instead.

The VGA display driver inside VT (not to be confused with the `vga` framebuffer driver, a kernel loadable module that is a separate thing) supports pretty much exactly what an old VGA card was capable of.  To get even Super VGA capability requires the `fb` display driver or the `efifb` display driver.

The `fb` display driver inside VT, in turn, apparently requires the presence of a *framebuffer* driver such as `vga`, `vga` with a `vesa` overlay, `nvidia`, or some such driver.  (The relationship between VT display and framebuffer drivers is undocumented, unfortunately.)  Those get loaded per what is compiled into the kernel, what is loaded at bootstrap time according to `loader.conf`, and what is loaded later with `kldload`.

The `efifb` display driver inside VT, requires that the kernel loader have detected EFI firmware and told the kernel about it.  (This is all undocumented, unfortunately.)

The `kern.vt.fb.default_mode` setting only applies if VT is using its `fb` display driver, and the *framebuffer* driver being used by that is a DRM2 a.k.a. KMS framebuffer driver.  (This is about the only part of this that *is* documented, in the vt(4) manual page.)

Old VGA hardware didn't have a 1280×768 mode.  It's as simple as that.